# "Especially" and commas

Tags: punctuation, commas

I'm curious about the correct usage of commas in the following sentence:

"Secondary electron emission from metallic and especially dielectric surfaces is a fundamental process of great technological significance."

I heard that one should put a comma before but not after especially. However, in my opinion the sentence looks kind of weird with a comma in front of especially. Can anyone assist me on this?

Comment: The current set of answers are addressing the word "especially" when used to start a dependent clause. If especially is not being used in this manner, these are not the rules used. Example: "I am especially happy to see you". No dependent clause, no commas.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

The rule you were taught is an over-generalization. The sentence written above is correct with no commas at all. The "rule" about *especially* only applies to the case when *especially* is being used as a parenthetical phrase, usually at the end of a sentence.

> We really like ice cream, **especially chocolate ice cream**.

This rule is not unique to the word *especially*, but is used for all sorts of sentence-final parentheticals:

> The "rule" about *especially* only applies to the case when *especially* is being used as a parenthetical phrase, **usually at the end of a sentence**.

Since your sentence is not using *especially* to begin a parenthetical statement, it does not require a comma. It is, however, stylistically awkward, and I would recommend the following revision:

> Secondary electron emission from metallic surfaces, especially dielectric surfaces, is a fundamental process of great technological significance

Comment: Thanks for your detailed answer. However, as pointed out in my comment to Barrie England's answer your suggestion of commas does imply a logically incorrect meaning because metallic and dielectric surfaces are two different things. So I guess it's probably the best to not put any commas at all.

Comment: A dash between especially and metallic could help a reader in your case.

"Secondary electron emission from metallic and especially-dielectric surfaces is a fundamental process of great technological significance."

Answer (score 2):

If you put any commas in that sentence at all, then put one  after *metallic* and another after *dielectric*.

Comment: I agree the suggested form (which JSBձոգչ also mentions at end of his or her answer) is grammatical, but I think in this case it gives the sentence a different meaning because of implying dielectric surfaces are metallic, which they need not be.

Comment: @jwpat7 You're right. In fact metallic and dielectric surfaces are two perfectly distinct things. I want to mention both but put a stress on the dielectric ones.